# SuiteScript : Update Case record Status - If Customer Message received

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Hope someone can help me wrap my head around this. I'm trying to trigger a Case Status change if a Customer interaction (email) is received.

Below is the code written to date:

```
function afterSubmit(type)
{

//load the case record
var caseRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('supportcase', nlapiGetRecordId());

//Get the Case Status of the assoicated Case
var caseStatus = caseRecord.getFieldValue('status');

//Get the Message value
var incomming = caseRecord.getFieldValue('incomingmessage');  


//Check current Status is none of Completed or Closed
if(caseStatus != '4' && caseStatus != '5')
{
    // If there is any activity
    if(incomming != '')
    {
         // Load the message record
        var message = nlapiGetNewRecord();

        // Get the ID of the activity associated with the message
        var activity = message.getFieldValue('activity');

            if (activity)
            {
                // If the activity is a case, load the record and change the status.
                try
                {
                    var caseRecord = nlapiLoadRecord('supportcase', activity);
                    caseRecord.setFieldValue('status',20);
                    nlapiSubmitRecord(caseRecord);
                }
                // If the activity is not a Case, log a warning message
                catch(exec)
                {
                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Warning','Activity Record is not a Case');
                }
            }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Note: Case Status 4 = Completed Case Status 5 = Closed Case Status 20 = Customer Reply Received
What is happening is? Once I save the case and I generate a mail to the customer i.e. case logged email. The case status is updated to "Customer Reply Received"

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, can I just point out that

```
if(caseStatus != '4' || caseStatus != '5')
```

*will always be* `true`.  You're testing whether caseStatus is NOT EQUAL TO 4 ***OR*** NOT EQUAL TO 5.  So if it *is* equal to 4 it will be not equal to 5, therefore true, and vice versa.  So I think what you were trying to do is:

```
if(caseStatus != '4' && caseStatus != '5')
```

or:

```
if(!(caseStatus == '4' || caseStatus == '5'))
```

With that out the way, it looks like you're loading the case and checking for any activity and changing the status based on that.  When you send a customer an email you are creating activity so there will always be activity and therefore the status will always be updated to '20'.  However, there seems to be some code missing because at the start of your script you set both `message` and `caseRecord` to the same thing so I might be misreading what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

You are right regarding the IF Statement and also the loading of the record.

Below is my updated code.

Now that you've opened my eyes. There is a realisation that "incommingmessage" is not a valid field id. I need to figure out.... how to load the "Interactions" tab to get the value of the "IncomingMessage" box.

I've made an update to the original code to reflect.